# How do I merge the results of two functions into a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to create an infinite list with fibonacci in a good spot. My original thought was just to call and then truncate the list returned by and then stick them together. I don't know how to just take the first element from the list. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: So you want `[f1, p1, f2, p2, ...]`? Any attempt from your side?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're basically looking for [indexing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) the fibonaccis at every prime:

```
result = [fibs !! p | p <- primes]
```

However, that's not really efficient, repeatedly scanning through the `fibs`. Better do it by repeatedly dropping a bit - the distance between every two primes - from the list, and taking the heads of each of the so-produced lists:

```
result = map head $ tail $ scanl (flip drop) fibs $ zipWith (-) primes (0:primes)
```

To use one-based indexing, it's

```
result = [fibs !! (p-1) | p <- primes]
result = map head $ tail $ scanl (flip drop) fibs $ zipWith (-) primes (1:primes)
```

Comment: @user2020493 That's exactly what my code is doing except it uses zero-based indexing for the positions :-)